# How to write query in grails controller

Tags: grails

I am using grails 1.3.7. I am sending username and password from my view page to controller. And it's rendering correctly on browser. But I need to write query for collect data with that username and password from database. But I have no idea how to write query in grails controller. Can anyone please help me on this ? Here is my action below where I want to write query for logging in to the home page >>>

```
def loginAction = {
    def username = params?.username
    def password = params?.password
    def val = username + "  ---  " +password
    render val
}
```

Comment: Did you read about GORM? http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html

Comment: @IgorArtamonov yes I have wrote "def b = User.get(1)" but it returns --- "com.User : 1" I have to check the user is valid or not How I can do it. any idea please

Comment: @IgorArtamonov thanks for your help but it shows the following error -- " Error 500: Executing action [loginAction] of controller [com.LoginController] caused exception: No such property: user for class: com.LoginController
Servlet: grails
URI: /ownProject/grails/login/loginAction.dispatch
Exception Message: No such property: user for class: com.LoginController
Caused by: No such property: user for class: com.LoginController
Class: LoginController
At Line: [22]  "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
def loginAction = {
    def username = params?.username
    def password = params?.password
    User user = User.findByUsername(username)
    def val = user?.password == password ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid'
    render val
}
```

But you really should read docs for GORM - http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html